# Why there seems to be unrelated packages when running yum install nodejs?

Tags: centos7, yum

When running yum install nodejs on Centos 7.4 I see a lot of packages that to my knowledge has nothing to do with nodejs.

Here is part of the list of the packages yum downloads:

```
nginx                                                                                                                                | 2.9 kB     00:00
nginx/primary_db                                                                                                                     |  41 kB     00:00
remi-php71                                                                                                                           | 3.0 kB     00:00
remi-php71/primary_db                                                                                                                | 207 kB     00:00
```

Does nodejs really need those packages? If not, why they are downloaded?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are not packages. They are package *repositories* you have installed on your system, which *contain* packages.